# PHP function on demand

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I have a custom tab in woocommerce that loops out spare parts to the current product. In some cases there are a lot of spare parts and the product takes a long time to load. Is there some smart way to only load the tab content “on demand” instead of every time the product is shown? The tab content is a wp-query loop.

This is part of the code:

```php
<?php
foreach( $categories as $category ):
    $categoryID = $category->term_id;
    $categoryName = $category->name;

    //Query

    // $argsParts = array(
    //     'post_type' => 'product',
    //     'tax_query' => array(
    //         array(
    //             'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    //             'terms' => $categoryID,
    //             'operator' => 'IN',
    //         )
    //     ),
    //     'meta_query' => array(
    //         array(
    //             'key' => '_crosssell_ids',
    //             'value' => $current_post_id,
    //             'compare' => 'LIKE'
    //         )
    //     )
    // );

    $argsParts = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'no_found_rows' => true,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__in' => $crosssells,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'terms' => $categoryID,
                'operator' => 'IN',
            )
        ),
    );

    $queryParts = new WP_Query($argsParts);

    if($queryParts->have_posts()){
    ?>
        <li class="g-acc-list__nav__button" id="g-acc-list__nav--<?php echo $categoryID ?>"><?php echo $categoryName ?></li>
    <?php
    }

endforeach;
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to load it on demand using Javascript and asynchronous requests. Though it's probably not a bad idea to optimize the query instead of having it in a loop

Comment: All right! Thank you! When you say optimize the query. How do you mean then in general? In this case it looks for cross-sells and loops through them. Is there a better way?

Comment: Probably using a join, but hard to say without having some specifics

Comment: Okay! I can paste the code tomorrow (12hr). If you could give just the slightest advice then I’d really appreciate it. :-)

Comment: Now, the code is in the question